# Removal of upvote/downvote button for self questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, design

I cannot upvote/downvote my questions/answers. Well, in that case, those buttons I think are not needed. I simply find it as an unwanted feature to see the button for self voting.

I agree with the alert message popped up when I do the same. But still removing that button will not tempt me to press that button.

Comment: if you know you can't upvote your own posts then why are you tempted to press the button?

Comment: Duplicate on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12599/remove-vote-ui-elements-beside-own-question-and-answer-posts

Comment: @bluefeet It has happened that I did a search, ran into a great answer that I thought I should upvote only to find out that I'm the one who wrote the answer in the first place. Oops... (This does not warrant a UI change, though.)

Comment: @Louis right but you try it once and realize you can't, are you really going to be tempted to do it again?  Probably not.

Comment: No harm in trying to press useless buttons.  Unless you make it so that either button downvotes your post.

Comment: It is [blooper #8](http://www.amazon.com/GUI-Bloopers-2-0-Second-Edition/dp/0123706432)

Answer (score 33):

Right. It'll replace that temptation with confusion. "Why is this button gone? Does this mean people can't vote on *my* answer? What did I do to deserve this?"

Putting the button there and then telling you that you can't use it makes this self-documenting: you know voting is *possible*, but not by you *because it's your own post*.

See also:

- [Don't hide or disable menu items?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12756/dont-hide-or-disable-menu-items)
- [Remove vote UI elements beside own question and answer posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12599/remove-vote-ui-elements-beside-own-question-and-answer-posts)

Comment: Yet, self-voting in the comments are solved by removing the buttons...