# Can I upvote or downvote my own question?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, self-answer

Can I upvote or downvote questions and answers asked and given by me? And even if I am able to upvote them, will my reputation increase because of that?

Also, if I answer my own question and then accept it, will my reputation increase?

Comment: No you can't upvote your own questions and answers. Accepting your own answer also won't raise your rep.

Comment: I just looked, and, shockingly, this doesn't seem to be a duplicate of any questions that were already asked on Meta Stack Overflow. So, I'm going to answer it.

Comment: to second Cody - congrats on actually asking a question no one wondered about voting (probably because it is self-explanatory). The closest cross-site dupe-ish Q&A is [this one from MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39194/786798) concerned with the inability to downvote oneself.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot vote on your own posts. Ever. The vote buttons are still shown, even on your own posts, [for the purposes of consistency](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255036/removal-of-upvote-downvote-button-for-self-questions), but they do not work. If you attempt to vote for one of your own posts, you'll be presented with an error message that says, essentially, you cannot do that.

You can vote on *answers* submitted by other people to your own question. I think it should be obvious why that is the case. The only things you cannot vote on are posts that you, yourself, posted. (Or, that you, yourself, posted from an alternate account. Technically, the system won't block this, because it sees them as two separate accounts, but operating multiple accounts in this fashion is an abuse of the system. When moderators catch this, we invalidate the votes and issue suspensions. So, it's not something you want to do.)

Since you cannot upvote or downvote your own posts, your reputation will not be increased or decreased.

Note that you can *accept* answers (the green checkmark) to your own questions, whether the answer was posted by you or by someone else. When you accept your own answer, you don't earn the +2 reputation that you normally get for accepting an answer. Also, you have to wait 2 days after posting before you can accept your own answer; the idea is to give other community members plenty of time to post *better* solutions before you jump to accepting the first thing you thought of. (Not that new, better answers cannot be posted later, even after an answer has been accepted.)

So, no, if you answer your own question and accept your answer, your reputation will not increase. But don't take that as a disincentive to answer your own question. If you've found a solution that works, we always appreciate you writing it up as an answer and sharing it with the community. The *important* thing here is to get good answers to questions; reputation is just a side benefit.

Fundamentally, the rule is that nothing you do *to yourself* can increase your reputation. If it could, that would be a massive abuse vector, leading to reputation fraud.

Comment: Plus it’s like talking to yourself: “yeah, this is a good post! Good job 10 Rep!”. For some reason on other sites you can do it (i.e youtube, and reddit).

Comment: Yeah, this is *exactly* what I was thinking, Cody. That's a really great answer! Thank you so much for taking the time to write and post it. I'd +1 this if I could. Your Meta participation recently has been truly outstanding. The site is so much better off with your wit and wisdom. (Seems I can talk to myself here, too.)

Comment: Self-fanboying is now a thing.

Comment: In some reddits you even AUTOMATICALLY upvote. Which means that posts effectively start in an index1 way, making it, useless?